# Getting TeamCity (Docker Linux) parameters or system properties in Cake (C#) returns nothing

Tags: c#, docker, teamcity-9.0, cakebuild

I'm trying to access the branch name in Cake on TeamCity running inside a Linux Docker container, but whenever I try to fetch any of the "Configuration Parameters", the values are returning nothing.

In my branch, the following build parameter values are visible on TeamCity:

**Configuration parameters**

- vcsroot.branch: refs/heads/master
- teamcity.build.branch: 5/merge

**Environment variables**

- env.vcsroot.branch: 5/merge

The `env.vcsroot.branch`variable has a value of `%teamcity.build.branch%`.

My cake script simply tries to spit out the values, and all of the ones below are coming back empty:

```
var branch = EnvironmentVariable("vcsroot.branch");
var tcbranch = EnvironmentVariable("teamcity.build.branch");
var agent = EnvironmentVariable("system.agent.name");
var confName = EnvironmentVariable("system.teamcity.buildConfName");
var buildId = EnvironmentVariable("teamcity.build.id");
var vcsRootBranch = EnvironmentVariable("vcsroot.Root_TemplatedVcsRoot1.branch");
var argOrEnv = ArgumentOrEnvironmentVariable("teamcity.build.branch", "vcsroot.branch", "Unfound");

Information($"vcsroot.branch = {branch}");
Information($"teamcity.build.branch = {tcbranch}");
Information($"system agent name = {agent}");
Information($"system TC build cof name= {confName}");
Information($"param buildId = {buildId}");
Information($"vcsroot template branch = {vcsRootBranch}");
Information($"test argument or env variables = {argOrEnv}");
```

The actual output:

```
[12:34:51][Step 1/2] vcsroot.branch = 
[12:34:51][Step 1/2] teamcity.build.branch = 
[12:34:51][Step 1/2] system agent name = 
[12:34:51][Step 1/2] system TC build cof name= 
[12:34:51][Step 1/2] param buildId = 
[12:34:51][Step 1/2] vcsroot template branch = 
[12:34:51][Step 1/2] test argument or env variables = Unfound
```

Oddly enough, on our non-docker Windows-based TeamCity agents, the values seem to return fine. I have a feeling I'm missing something here that's painfully simple, but I'm a relative novice when it comes to Cake, TeamCity, and Docker. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: to claify, most of the environment variables are coming back as expected; the only one that I've noticed that doesn't is the one that references a configuration parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out...

First off, I missed the subtext on the TC project parameters page for Configuration Parameters; it states `Configuration parameters are not passed into build, can be used in references only`.

Secondly, I didn't realize that none of the System Properties were visible (don't know if that's an issue), but its subtext also states `System properties will be passed into the build (without system. prefix), they are only supported by the build runners that understand the property notion`.

Therefore, in order to get the Configuration Parameter value, I needed to create an Environment Variable using the Configuration Parameter as it's value:

```
env.TCBranch = %teamcity.build.branch%
```

It was a little unsettling that `teamcity.build.branch` didn't show up in the type-ahead when specifying the value, but it works.

This begs the question about why the Environment Value of `env.vcsroot.branch` didn't work, and I presume it's because the name of the variable is identical to a different Configuration Variable name. Considering these parameters aren't passed into the build, I don't see why that should matter, but I can't think of why else it wouldn't work. Anyway, thanks to @devlead for the suggestions (above).

Answer (score 2):

For Environment variables TeamCity replaces non alpha numeric characters with "_"

I.e `vcsroot.branch` becomes `vcsroot_branch`

Comment: You know, I had seen this listed, but thought (for some reason) it only applied to powershell. Either way, I tried converting the variable names to use the underscores, to no avail. Thanks for the suggestion, though!

Comment: You could use EnvironmentVariables alias to list all keys available https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common/EnvironmentAliases/97336C76

Comment: Yeah, that's a great idea...I'll try that now. Thanks again!

Comment: Oh man, I'm an idiot...I forgot to mention that most of the environment vars are returning valid values, just not the one that references a configuration parameter. I've edited the orig post to reflect that. Anyway, it returned a bunch of our env vars with valid values; unfortunately, none of them can be used to determine the branch. I'll see if there's a way to grab the parameters, but I'm not holding my breath.